# Nested Control Visibility Question

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, visibility

Noticed this while working through a bug this morning.  I've got something like this on my page:

```
<div id="dvDropShipMsgWrap" runat="server" visible="false" class="systemMsgCon">
    <div id="dvDropShipMsg" class="systemMsg plus">
        <asp:Label ID="lblAttributeDropShipMsg" runat="server" ForeColor="#333333" Visible="false"
            Style="font-weight: normal;"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And had this in the code behind:

```
if(myCondition)
    lblAttributeDropShipMsg.Visible = p.DropShipable;
else
    <snip>

dvDropShipMsgWrap.Visible = p.DropShipable;
```

Tracing the code, I found that the lblAttributeDropShipMsg.Visible property would always be false, even when setting it to true.  Changing it to this:

```
dvDropShipMsgWrap.Visible = p.DropShipable;
lblAttributeDropShipMsg.Visible = p.DropShipable;
```

fixed the problem.

It seems weird that I can't set the nested control's visibility before setting its parent.  Can anybody provide some enlightenment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran some tests, using exactly the same declarative markup as in your example. My code behind is shown below. Comments on the right show the values of the two elements' `.Visible` properties, after the code to the left of each comment executes. I've used local varialbes `parent` and `child` to make things a bit clearer.

```
 1   var parent = dvDropShipMsgWrap;             //  parent  child
 2   var child = lblAttributeDropShipMsg;        //  false   false  (initial values)
 3   child.Visible = true;                       //  false   false 
 4   parent.Visible = true;                      //  true    true
 5   parent.Visible = false;                     //  false   false
 6   child.Visible = false;                      //  false   false
 7   parent.Visible = true;                      //  true    false
```

I think the result on line 3 is probably the behavior that you observed. But there's more going on here than it may seem at first.

If you look at the CIL code that gets/sets a control's `.Visible` property, you will find that setting a control's value actually does affect the value of an internal bit flag, regardless of the visibility of the parent. However, when getting the value of a control's `.Visible` property, the code traverses a path starting at the given control, up to its parent, then to the parent's parent, and so on, up toward the root of the control hierarchy.  If the internal bit flag of any control along the way indicates "not visible", the traversal stops, and the value `false` is returned. The only way to return `true` is if the traversal makes it all the way to the root, without finding any control that is not visible.

So, to sum up, setting a control's `.Visible` property is "remembered" internally, but the value of the property will be returned as `false` if any of its ancestors is not visible. When the all the ancestors of the control are made visible, the value of the control's `.Visible` property will be the "remembered" value from when it was last set.